# SSL Page Posting to Non Secure Form

Tags: php, forms, ssl, https, web

I have a page that requires SSL because of secure content being transmitted. However I have a third party embedded form on the page which posts to a third party site which does not have an SSL Installed. It works fine except that I get an annoying message by my browser.

"Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?"

Is there anyway I can get around this?

Comment: No. You can't mix and match or you will always get that message by design.

Comment: i hope not, since that would compromise browser security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no control over the third party application and they have no ssl enabled, than **no**

Only chance: If the third party has https enabled, you could try to modify the `<form action=""` attribute to use https, just after site load. But you told that they don't have.

A hacky last chance: You could serve a HTTPS proxy on your site that talks non HTTPS to the third party site. Then modifiy the form action after site load to use that proxy.

So my advices are:

- Try to talk (email)  to the third party and tell them about your problem. Maybe they will help.
- If the first doesn't help than use my proxy attempt. Could be easily implemented in PHP. I can give an example if you want.

Comment: C'mon, the question states "third party site which does not have an SSL Installed".

Comment: Your answer is basically "if what you said in your question stops being an issue, you won't have an issue".